# Stripe createToken curious

Tags: javascript, stripe-payments, payment-gateway, payment

I'm very new with stripe. After dig into it, I'm curious about how createToken method call outside the stripe iframe but can collect iframe data (suppose we have separate element like cardNumber, cardCvc...) then use it to generate token (maybe it make a request to get token with card info).

Anyone who know please explain to me, thanks in advance.

P/S: I've had a look at Stripe v2 docs https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js/v2 (card.createToken section), previously it read credit card info directly from DOM value
[image]

But currently createToken 1st argument is the stripe element.

[image]
So I think the credit card info will be somewhere in the element? And only stripe function (such as createToken) know how to retrieve info from it?

Comment: Yes, the credit card data itself is in the Element(which is an iframe hosted on Stripe's servers), and you can't access it, since that would put you in increased PCI compliance scope, which you don't want. You just get the non-sensitive token, and can use that to complete charging the customer.

Comment: But in stripe element, I saw the submit button is outside the stripe iframe and when the submit event occur, it call createToken method so I think in somewhere the method would read the card info (this method run on the main thread not the iframe)

Comment: that's internal to stripe.js and isn't really something you need to think about. When you call createToken, stripe.js collects the information from the Element and creates the token and returns it to your code, and you use the token to charge the card it represents.

Comment: Yes, I know it was handled in internal stripe js, I'm just curious about how it secure when the main thread (not iframe) run the createToken method so maybe it extract the card info in the main script